# Not getting the BSD General Commands Manual for builtins on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, bash, raspbian-buster

I'm on Raspbian buster

I specifically want the builtin manual just to read it, but entering `man cd` just outputs "No manual entry for builtin." I know I could get documentation on builtins using help, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I can get it on my mac with the same command but not on my Raspberry pi. Just wondering why it's not available on Raspbian's bash.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  The cd command is built-in to the bash shell, i.e. it is a bash command.  To see the details of bash built-ins do `man bash` and search for `cd`.

Comment: I mean the builtin man page. It doesn't come up when I type in man cd, man fg, or any builtin

Comment: Raspbian is Linux not BSD.